# How to solve Jquery Datepicker Validation issue?

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker

I did jquery validation on my form in play framework which is working properly when i directly click on submit button without entering values in textboxes validation messages come. 
  But the issue is, when i am selecting a date from datepicker(bootstrap-datepicker.js), validation message does not disappear for date field. after clicking twice it disappears. please help me.

```
Jquery Code:
$("form input.date").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        onClose: function() {
            $(this).valid();
        }
```

});

```
Validation Function:
$("#register").validate({
        focusCleanup: true,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
                number:true,
                minlength:10,
                maxlength:10
            },                
            date:{
                required: true,
                date: true
            }                
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please provide your full name",
            email: {
                required: "Please provide your email address",
                email: "Please provide a valid email address"
            },
            phone: {
                required: "Please provide your mobile number",
                number: "Please provide a valid mobile number",
                minlength:"Please provide a valid mobile number",
                maxlength:"Please provide a valid mobile number"
            },               
            date: {
                required: "Please select date ",
                date: "Please select valid date"
            }                
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue and found a solution here:
[jQuery validator and datepicker click not validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335120/jquery-validator-and-datepicker-click-not-validating)

Op was very close, issue resolved with following (modified) code from user Sparky:

```
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   }).change(function() {
         $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test        
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specify when your validation function will be executed, there is 'keyup' which execute your function when you finish the inputs filling.
this is the documentation [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
you verify your the date and if it's correct you use the function hide(), but remember the validation code should be inside keyup()