# jQuery validator and datepicker click not validating

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator to validate text inputs. The problem I have is, if I click submit it displays all error message correctly. However, on the datepicker input, to clear the error message I have to select the datepicker twice. ie; 1 click to select and it inputs the data correctly. 2nd click to clear the error message.

I read somewhere about using an 'on' event on the datepicker, so I tried that, but it made no difference. I don't think that is coded correctly. I am assuming that the invalid and success classes are part of the validator script. Worth a try.

What could be happening here. Thanks

Sciprt code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '2011:2037',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            minDate: 0,
            defaultDate: null
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if($('#datepicker').valid()){
       $('#datepicker').removeClass('invalid').addClass('success');   
    }
 });

    });
</script>
```

html code

```
<label for"datepicker">
   <input id="datepicker" name="datepicker" type="text" />
</label>
```

validator relevant code

Rules/Message section

```
 datepicker:
    {
        required: true,
        date: true
    },

 datepicker:
    {
        required: " * required: You must enter a destruction date",
        date: "Can contain digits only"
    }
```

Comment: Your question is very lacking. Where is the rest of the call to `.validate()`? Since you're using a date picker, why do you need the `date` rule?  Which datepicker plugin??  What is the `changeDate` event supposed to be?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"I have to select the datepicker twice. ie; 1 click to select and it inputs the data correctly. 2nd click to clear the error message."*

That's because validation is normally triggered on `keyup` and `blur` events.  Since you're using a date-picker to interact with the field, rather than the keyboard, you're interfering with the normal triggering events.

Your code is supposed to compensate, but is over-kill...

```
$(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ ... })
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    if($('#datepicker').valid()){
       $('#datepicker').removeClass('invalid').addClass('success');   
    }
 });
    });
```

You only need to call the `.valid()` method on the field whenever the value changes.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ ... })
        .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
            $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
            // '$(this)' refers to '$("#datepicker")'
        });
});
```

However, this is basically the same as you had before.

What is `changeDate` supposed to be?  Is this something defined by your datepicker plugin?  That's not a standard jQuery event, so likely the whole problem.  Try the standard `change` event instead....

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '2011:2037',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate: 0,
        defaultDate: null
    }).on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
        // '$(this)' refers to '$("#datepicker")'
    });
});
```

Comment: it says .valid() is not a function. What should i do?

Comment: @vignesh.   You should include the jQuery Validate plugin!   Since `.valid()` is a method of this plugin, the error means you have not properly included it.

Comment: It should be noticed that `datepicker`.[onSelect](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) actually worked for me.

Comment: @sanojlawrence, you cannot attach `.validate()` to anything other than the form object.  `$(this).parsley()` does not represent your form.  Please do not start entirely new questions in comments.

Answer (score 8):

Sparky's answer worked great for me, the only thing I would change is instead of using the id, I just used the jquery this in the on function, ie:

```
    .on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid();  
    });
```

That just makes it a little more general..
-D

Comment: Incorporated this suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Jquery Form Validator(http://www.formvalidator.net/)
and you want to use bootstarp datepicker then just add class="hasDatepicker" to input element.It worked for me.

```
<input type="text" name='birth_date' class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" value=""  data-validation="birthdate" data-validation-format="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

Comment: Except that this whole question is about a completely different plugin.  [jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net) is not the [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).   Please pay attention to the tags on the question, which clearly direct you to the plugin being asked about.