# Datepicker validation not functioning on first try

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I am currently working on a site using MEAN. In this site, I am using html5 datepicker but since it is not supported on some browsers, I used jquery datepicker as fallback and successfully managed to make it work.

Another thing I want is to display an error message if the user's selected date is valid. A date is valid if it is between `1900-01-01` and the current date.

Now, the problem is whenever I select a date for the first time, I am getting the error message even though I selected a valid date. And upon selecting a valid date for the second time, the error message disappears. On the third try, I selected an invalid date but the error doesn't show. On the fourth try, I selected a valid date but the error displays. To make it short, the validation applies to the previous input and not on the current input.

Below is the code on my **controller**:

```
var elem = document.createElement('input');
elem.setAttribute('type', 'date');
if ( elem.type === 'text' ) {
  $('#contactBirthdate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
}

$scope.checkDate = function() {
  console.log('Entered check date funtion');
  var now = new Date();
  var minDate = new Date('1900-01-01');
  var inputDate;
  if ( elem.type === 'text' ) {
    $scope.appointment.birthday =  new Date($( "#contactBirthdate" ).val());
    console.log('input date not supported');
    inputDate = new Date($scope.appointment.birthday);
  } else {
    inputDate = new Date($scope.appointment.birthday);
  }
  console.log('inputDate ' + inputDate);
  if (inputDate < now && inputDate > minDate) {
    $scope.isValidDate = true;
  } else {
    $scope.isValidDate = false;
  }
  console.log($scope.isValidDate);
};
```

And in my **HTML**

```
<div class="form-field">
   <input name="contactBirthdate" type="date" min="1900-01-01" max="{{minAge | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" id="contactBirthdate" placeholder="Your Birthdate"
    value="" class="full-width" ng-model="appointment.birthday" required="" step="1" ng-blur="checkDate()" onkeydown="return false">
   <label ng-show="contactForm.contactBirthdate.$touched && !isValidDate" id="contactName-error" class="error" for="contactBirthdate">
    Invalid Birthdate</label>
 </div>
```

I really hope someone can help me with this one.

Comment: Look at this answer and I think it may help you in yours. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22338363/5117508

Comment: @axhi i really do appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I still can't make it work. Anyway, thank you very much.