# Validate date field on focusout with jquery-validation

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate, bootstrap-datepicker

Date Input Field not valid, When first time selecting the date.
       Its showing required error message,  because of field have an empty value(*check console log*). But field will be valid on second change.

Notes: A cause is that date input field loses focus when picking the date (click event). But the date populates only later changed when the click event happens. But validator will validate field on focus out event.

I'm validating a form using [Jquery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/), using [bootstrap-datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for Widget.

^^for Better UX Run code snippet on full-page ;)
or 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y649qhgp/13/)

from @Sparky / @Vignesh ans: Yes, its a workaround for this, We can use change/hide/changeDate(module attribute) event handler. It gets triggered once the input values have been set.
But the problem is whenever we pick from year->month->date each clicks in the picker, removes focus from input and focusout event fired and showing the error message until choosing the date.

It's not flat like choice field. in choice field there is no focusout event triggered until choosing the option from field widget. Like this, How can we move around the year/month/date options without seeing error message?.

**jQuery:** & **HTML**

```js
    $(function() {
      $("#editEventForm").validate({
        rules: {
          full_name: {
            required: true,
          },
          event_date: {
            required: true,
          },
        },
        messages: {
          full_name: "Please enter your full name!",
          event_date: "Please enter valid date!",
        },
        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
          var e = $(element);
          e.closest('.has-feedback').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
          var e = $(element);
          e.closest('.has-feedback').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        },
        onfocusout: function(element) {
          console.log("element value --> ", $(element).val());
          return $(element).valid();
        },
      });
      $('#eventDate').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
      }).on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid(); // triggers a validation test
        // $(this) refers to $('#eventDate')
      });

    });
```

```css
.has-error :focus {
  border-color: #f84545 !important;
}
.error {
  color: #f84545;
}
```

```html
<link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="bsdp-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>



<form id="editEventForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="has-feedback">
      <label for="eventDate">Full Name * </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fullName" name="full_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="has-feedback">
      <label for="eventDate">Event Date * </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="eventDate" name="event_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="ClickMe">
</form>
```

Comment: Duplicate of this:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/22335120/594235

Comment: @Sparky Yes, already I have gone through. But how can we move around year/month/date options without triggering the error message?

Comment: @ramganesh Updated my answer. Pls have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** : Click event moves the focus to the clicked element. Hence on clicking the date in the picker, removes focus from input and `focusout` event fired. Before setting the input value, the picker performs various operations. Hence value remains empty on `focusout`. Hence the alert remains in the UI.

**Explanation** : On clicking/focusing the `date` field, `datepicker` opens. The real problem occurs when you click on the `date` in the `datepicker`. Once it is clicked you can see the date field looses the focus (the blinking caret disappears) immediately. The picker closes immediately as we configured `autoclose:true`. The following is the hide functionality written inside the datepicker.

```
hide: function() {
        return this.isInline || !this.picker.is(":visible") ? this : (this.focusDate = null,
        this.picker.hide().detach(),
        this._detachSecondaryEvents(),
        this.setViewMode(this.o.startView),
        this.o.forceParse && this.inputField.val() && this.setValue(),
        this._trigger("hide"),
        this)
```

1. Makes the picker to hide.
2. `detach()` makes the associated elements to be removed, keeping the element details untouched incase the elements are reinserted again.
3. Removes the attached Secondary events from the datepicker.
4. Sets the viewmode to the configured one (as it is not configured in our problem, it sets to the default one).
5. Parses the selected value and sets the parsed result to the input box.
6. Runs the custom callback (if any), configured in the options

So before setting the value in the input the `onfocusout` event gets fired. And as there is no value present at that time, the error is shown.

To prevent this from happening, add a `hide` event handler in the picker (as below), and handle the same validation from there. This custom event handler gets triggered once the input values has been set (as explained above).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#editEventForm").validate({
    rules: {
      full_name: {
        required: true,
      },
      event_date: {
        required: true,
      },
    },
    messages: {
      full_name: "Please enter your full name!",
      event_date: "Please enter valid date!",
    },
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
  });
  $('#eventDate').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom right"
  }).on("hide",function(){
      $("#editEventForm").data("validator").settings.ignore="";
      $(this).valid();
  }).on("focus",function(){
      $("#editEventForm").data("validator").settings.ignore="#eventDate, :hidden";
  });
});
```

```html
<link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="bsdp-css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>



<form id="editEventForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <label for="eventDate">Full Name * </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="fullName" name="full_name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="eventDate">Event Date * </label>
      <input class="form-control" id="eventDate" name="event_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="ClickMe">
</form>
```

**Edit** : As already told, we cannot prevent `focusout` event from firing. But the requirement can be achieved with a workaround.

On focus, `ignore` the validation and on `hide`, remove the ignored validation and validate.

To be clear, ignore the validation for the specified element via

```
$("#editEventForm").data("validator").settings.ignore="#eventDate, :hidden";`
```

(`:hidden` is the default value, so don't omit it). During validation, the plugin internally uses the jQuery `not` selector to ignore elements. On hiding the datepicker (either by selecting date/clickoutside), remove the element from the config and apply validation.

Comment: @ramganesh Updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: :) yes Its working fine as expected, and I just simplifying your's stuff. see my ans.

Answer (score 2):

Question can not be [closed as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22335120/594235) because of bounty.

The jQuery Validate plugin automatically triggers a validation test on focus out and key up of normal form input fields, and do not work well with the date picker.

You'll have to programmatically trigger validation whenever you pick a date:

```
$('#eventDate').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    // endDate: '+45d', // show current date - next 45 days
}).on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();  // triggers a validation test
    // $(this) refers to $('#eventDate')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying the @Vignesh workaround.

We can skip the field validation `onfocusout`, and we do the validaion on `hide` event

```
// here we can skip the validation
onfocusout: function(element) {
  var elementId = element.getAttribute('id');
  if (elementId === "eventDate") {
    // datepicker widget - don't do validation on focusout event
    return false;
  }
  return $(element).valid();
},


// here we can do the validation
$('#eventDate').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
}).on('hide', function() {
  // datepicker - on hide do the field validation
  $('#eventDate').valid();
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ow5u7qr8/2/)

Comment: Yeah.. it can be done like that too.... But I wanted to expose the method that does the same internally, should be known to you and whomever it may help.

Answer (score -2):

You can set a date at first load in the date picker.

```
$('#eventDate').datepicker({
                autoclose: true 
            }).datepicker("setDate", 'now');
```

Comment: it's for Set today's date as default date.